# Tangent line, normal line - confusing.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, derivatives, tangent-line

I am practicing finding tangent and normal line. The tangent/normal line is usually to some graph, and parallel/perpendicular to some other line at the same time. Not that complicated.

Can someone, **please**, verify my solutions? The more I study the less I know, and I don't even know how much I don't know. Thank you!

But I'm confused, mostly about the $a$ "directional coefficient" of $y=ax+b$ part.

Let's say the task is: **Find tangent and normal lines to the function $f(x) = \ln(x+1)$, parallel&perpendicular to $y=\frac{1}{2}x$**. (so 4 variations in total.)

What I know: I do know that if a line has to be parallel to other line, then the $a$ coefficients have to be the same. And if perpendicular, then I have to inverse it and change the sign.

What I am not sure of: how to properly write the equations. How to properly substitute into the equations. I am doing mistakes here related to $a$ coefficient.

I am looking for an algorithmic way so I can easily understand and remember how to solve it.

$f(x) = \ln(x+1)$

$f'(x) = \frac{1}{x+1}$

**1.** Finding tangent parallel to $y=\frac{1}{2}x$.

$\frac{1}{x+1} = \frac{1}{2}$

$x = 1 = x_{0}$

$f(x_{0}) = f(1) = \ln2$

$\Rightarrow y = \frac{1}{2}x - \frac{1}{2} + \ln2$

**2.** Finding tangent perpendicular to $y=\frac{1}{2}x$

$\frac{1}{x+1} = -2$

$x = 1 = x_{0}$

$f(x_{0}) = f(1) = \ln2$

$\Rightarrow y - \ln2 = -2(x-x_{0})$

$\Rightarrow y = -2x + 2 + \ln2$

**3.** Finding normal line parallel to $y = \frac{1}{2}x$

$\frac{1}{x+1} = -2$

$x = \frac{-3}{2} = x_{0}$

$f(x_{0}) = f(-\frac{3}{2})= \ln(\frac{-1}{2})$ - does not exist

$y = \frac{1}{2}(x-x_{0})$

$y = \frac{1}{2}x + \frac{3}{4}$

**4.** Finding normal line perpendicular to $y = \frac{1}{2}x$

$\frac{1}{x+1} = -2$

$x = \frac{-3}{2} = x_{0}$

$f(x_{0}) = f(\frac{-3}{2}) = \ln(\frac{-1}{2})$ - does not exist

$y - 0 = -2(x-x_{0})$

$y = -2x - 3$

Thanks for your time!

Comment: On a  quick read these look good to me. The exposition is clear. I suggest that a good way to check for common sense is to sketch a graph of the function and the three (of four) lines. You could see why the fourth is impossible.

Comment: Um, assuming my calculations are correct (are they?!), then why would 4th be impossible? :o I got 4 different $y=ax+b$ lines solutions.

Comment: Draw the picture! That curve always has positive slope so it can't have a normal line with positive slope. (I haven't checked your calculations.)

Comment: Your calculations aren’t correct for the last three parts. I think the concept of finding the slope is what’s confusing you, as you’ve mentioned. I’ve posted an explanation for the first two parts. Can you go through it and see if you can solve the last two parts?

Answer (score 2):

It’s not that difficult once you get the hang of the plan. Basically, in a question involving a function $f(x)$ and finding its tangent/normal lines at a particular point, you’d want to carry out the following steps:

- Find the general formula for a slope at a given point by computing the derivative $f’(x)$.
- Find the $x$-coordinate that satisfies the given conditions. Then, plug in the $x$-value obtained back into $f(x)$ to get the $y$-coordinate.
- Use point-slope form, or $y-y_1 = m(x-x_1)$ to find the equation.

which you seem to know.

---

For the example you’ve given, we have $f(x) = \ln(x+1)$, so $f’(x) = \frac{1}{x+1}$ as you’ve found.

---

$(a)$ For the tangent parallel to $y = \frac{1}{2}x$, you immediately obtain $m = \frac{1}{2}$, so $m_{tangent} = \frac{1}{2}$ as well.

- $$f’(x) = \frac{1}{2} \iff \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{x+1} \iff x = 1$$
- $$f(1) = \ln(1+1) = \ln 2$$
- $$y-y_1 = m(x-x_1) \implies y-\ln 2 = \frac{1}{2}(x-1) \implies \boxed{y = \frac{1}{2}x-\frac{1}{2}+\ln 2}$$

---

$(b)$ For the tangent perpendicular to $y = \frac{1}{2}x$, $m = \frac{1}{2}$, but $m\cdot m_{tangent} = -1$, so $m_{tangent} = -2$.

- $$f’(x) = -2 \iff -2 = \frac{1}{x+1} \iff x = -\frac{3}{2} = -1.5$$
- $$f(-1.5) = \ln(1+(-1.5)) = \ln(-0.5)$$

But wait, $\ln(-0.5)$ is not defined. Clearly there is an issue.

The issue is that $f’(x)$ can’t possibly be negative. Recall that in logs, the argument must be positive:

$$f(x) = \ln(1+x); \quad x > -1$$

$$f’(x) = \frac{1}{1+x}; \quad x > -1$$

So $f’(x)$ can’t be negative, which is why we have this problem. Therefore, you can’t have a tangent with a negative slope for this function. You can observe this in the graph of [$f(x) = \ln(x+1)$](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/imvf5gc7hd), which never curves downward at any point.

---

You use the exact same plan for normal lines, except you also have to note that

$$m_{tangent}\cdot m_{normal} = -1 \iff m_{normal} = -\frac{1}{m_{tangent}}$$

Since for the given problem, the tangent line’s slope is always positive, the normal line’s slope will always be negative.

Another tip I can give you is to use the connection between tangent lines and normal lines to your advantage and save time.

For instance, you can do the following:

- Find $x$ such that the normal line is perpendicular to $y = \frac{1}{2}x$.
- $\implies$ Find $x$ such that the tangent line is parallel to $y = \frac{1}{2} x$.

and

- Find $x$ such that the normal line is parallel to $y = \frac{1}{2}x$.
- $\implies$ Find $x$ such that the tangent line is perpendicular to $y = \frac{1}{2} x$.

Which essentially skips the entire first step since you already calculated those points in the first two parts. (Of course, this is only for finding the $x$-coordinate. Don’t confuse this for the slopes and equations of the lines themselves! They’re completely different lines, but intersect at the same point.)